# Placing the arrow up higher than the fraction bar

Tags: fractions

I want to have an arrow as the below image upper than the fraction bar and have it cover part of the fraction bar so I can change its position(preferably without appealing to a package). 
Also is there any better way to reproduce the barred S than the cancel package?
(sorry I  didn't make the second fraction)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mbox{S_1}}{\mbox{\cancel{S}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mbox{S_1}}` will produce an error as `_` can only be used in math mode. You want `\mathrm{S}_1`

Comment: why ask "without packages" ? you are apparently happy to use a class file such as `article` so why not a package such as `amsmath` ?

Comment: because I may need to use non english characters say persian(xepersian package) ones instead and I fear there would exist incompatibility issues with packages.

Comment: You are far less likely to have incompatibility  when using code from a package like amsmath that has been tested by people using many languages for over 25 years, than if you just use some code that one of us made up this morning with minimal testing to answer a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The suggested input would produce a lot of error messages, don't ignore error messages!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_1}{\cancel{\mathrm{S}}}
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\longrightarrow}{}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_2}{a}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and informing comment. Also your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Without packages (as requested).  I use `\ooalign` in lieu of the `cancel` package, and a simple `\raisebox` to change the baselines of the fractions (alternately, one could change the baseline of the `\rightarrow` as shown in the 2nd example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{%
  $\displaystyle\frac{S_1}{\ooalign{\kern.7pt/\cr$S$}}$} 
\rightarrow 
\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{%
  $\displaystyle\frac{S_2}{a}$} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one really wants it in a non-italic setting.  Also, here, I raise the arrow rather than lowering the fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_1}{\ooalign{/\cr S}} 
\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{${}\rightarrow{}$}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_2}{\mathrm{a}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

The OP asks about controlling the height/width of the slash.  With the addition of packages, it can be done.  Here, I stretch it horizontally by a factor of 2 and vertically compress it to 70% of its original height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_1}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\scalebox{2}[.7]{/}}{S}}
\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{${}\rightarrow{}$}
\frac{\mathrm{S}_2}{\mathrm{a}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I control the height and width of the diagonal line?

Comment: @nima Please see my answer **Follow Up**

Answer (score 2):

These don't seem to be fractions; in any case, using a table is easier. I present two versions, one with text style entries, one with math letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
S\textsubscript{1} & ${}\to{}$ & S\textsubscript{2} \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-1}
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{3-3}
\cancel{S} && a
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
S_{1} & {}\to{} & S_{2} \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-1}
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{3-3}
\cancel{S} && a
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the first with a `\barredS` command, without `cancel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\newcommand{\barredS}{%
  \leavevmode
  {\ooalign{S\cr\noalign{\kern-0.2ex}\hidewidth/\hidewidth\cr}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
S\textsubscript{1} & ${}\to{}$ & S\textsubscript{2} \\
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-1}
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{3-3}
\barredS && a
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think they are not fractions? I ask because I want to know what's your conception of a fraction.

Comment: @nima If they were fractions, the arrow should be level with the fraction bar.

Comment: thank you. and by the way I think it might be called matheme.